# gdb demangler segfault on loading symbols

Tags: linux, c++11, gcc, segmentation-fault, gdb

Recently, I started having troubles debugging my product with GDB.
I found the root of the problem, but not yet a workaround.

My code is written in C++11 with extensive use of meta programming.
To catch and fix possible crashes, it is compiled with debug info, which is used for demangling on SIGSEGV handler.

Extending the project made some of the tuples grow pretty big.

I narrowed the problem down to: uncomment one type in one tuple, and catch a SegFault in gdb on loading symbols.

Googling this appeared a to be a tedious task.
And debugging gdb with gdb haven't brought more insight either.
The only thing I found - is a [similar bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdb/+bug/1315590), but that tracker states it is fixed and confirmed fixed in my version of gdb (7.7.1)

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 as a dev-box, Centos7 for production servers, and here is the output of "gdb --args gdb ":

```
xxx@xxx$ gdb --args gdb ./epayworker
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from gdb...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /usr/bin/gdb ./epayworker
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./epayworker...
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000719da1 in cplus_demangle_print_callback ()
(gdb) bt -25
#0  0x0000000000719da1 in cplus_demangle_print_callback ()
#1  0x0000000000719fb4 in ?? ()
#2  0x000000000071a0c7 in ?? ()
#3  0x000000000071a26e in cplus_demangle_v3 ()
#4  0x000000000070c3c6 in cplus_demangle ()
#5  0x000000000068fdbb in bfd_demangle ()
#6  0x000000000055f269 in symbol_set_names ()
#7  0x00000000005cb985 in prim_record_minimal_symbol_full ()
#8  0x00000000004f82ba in ?? ()
#9  0x00000000004f8b95 in ?? ()
#10 0x000000000056a8d9 in ?? ()
#11 0x000000000056a459 in ?? ()
#12 0x000000000056a9b4 in symbol_file_add ()
#13 0x000000000056aa15 in ?? ()
#14 0x00000000005921be in catch_command_errors_const ()
#15 0x0000000000594da5 in ?? ()
#16 0x000000000059205a in catch_errors ()
#17 0x0000000000595244 in gdb_main ()
#18 0x000000000045391e in main ()
(gdb)
```

I'm not really excited about changing compiler for the core of our production servers at this stage. And bugs creating limitations to architecture is also not the best thing.

So my questions are: 
am I missing some type of flag to overcome some internal limitation in gdb? or this is just a bug in gdb? or maybe I should not be afraid and migrate for newer compiler version?

Thanks, for any help with my confusion.

**Update:**

It appeared to be a pretty die situation.
Recently I've been playing with tuples, and it seems that the problem is not related to some specific symbol, but to some kind of buffer overrun.
Because swapping types back and forth, renaming them, shrinking name lengths, is not making difference, but after some threshold on amount of types in the tuple, crash appears.

The biggest tuple typename length I've found is ~77600 characters (add one more type to it - gdb crash)

Side note is that Netbeans 8.0.2 also bugs with them: in call stack window on typenames with a big name length, after some threshold, it starts to make some kind of wrapping, and printing different parts of the same typename on top of the same line, making it completely unreadable. After some bigger threshold, typename just disappears making line empty.

I will file a bug.
But for obvious reasons, I cannot release my code to the public.
So I will try to extract the part that makes this mess, and build a test-app with it.
The part is: meta-functions used for building reflection, like meta-for_each and so on.

Sorry, deadlines are harsh now, so as soon as will have a little bit more time.

Comment: Latest gdb 7.8.2-0ubuntu1 behaves the same.

Comment: Have you tried to debug a simple empty app built with same tool chain as your target application?

Comment: Looks like a gdb bug to me. Perhaps you can file a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The demangler, perhaps somewhat surprisingly, is a complicated bit of software.  And, as C++ evolves, the mangling scheme becomes more complicated, and thus so does the demangler.  Sometimes there are bugs.

Now, ordinarily this is not a big deal.  But, to provide a good user experience (and also partially due to historical issues with compiler DWARF generation), gdb demangles symbols eagerly.  And if one such symbol triggers a demangler bug -- boom!

That's what you've experienced.

This past year a patch went in to wrap calls to the demangler with a SEGV catcher.  This way gdb can be at least a little insulated from demangler bugs -- it prints the offending symbol and attempts to soldier on.

Your gdb has probably been patched to fix the demangler for some specific known bugs, but probably does not yet have the SEGV catching patch.  So I would suggest you upgrade gdb.  This should help.

Also, let me recommend following Gary's bug-reporting instructions here: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14963#c35.  That is, if you know the symbol, file a GCC bug; otherwise file a gdb bug with a reproducer and someone will triage it.

To my knowledge there is no *reasonable* workaround for this bug.  That is why the SEGV catcher went in.  However there is an unreasonable workaround -- edit the binaries to rename the offending symbols to avoid demangler crashes.  But, really, it is simpler and safer to just build your own gdb.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I will file a bug later. I haven't found any solution to my problem yet, so I will give the patch you mention a try now. Should I keep this open until I find some way to overcome this?

Comment: Also, for completeness sake: gdb crashes even with no debug info generated.

Comment: If the mangled name in question appears in the ELF symbol table (sometimes called a "linker symbol" or something like that), then it will still provoke a crash even without debuginfo.  That's because gdb tries to read the linker symbols as well.